# How to make bottom sheet with "Apply" button which does not move until top sheet content gone

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[image][image]

This bottom sheet is normal as others but it has the button at the very bottom which does not move on swiping down until the top content disappearing.

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/android-bottom-sheet-behavior-and-animated-button-on-top-of-it-da86a9bfe545

Comment: Link above is for xml-android rather than compose itself. Anyway, could you please be more specific about your question? I did not understand